# how to avoid reusable custom cell from overwriting data when scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift

This is the code I am using and it works fine until I scroll in the table view, the cells overwrite each others and all the repostedFromLabel are hidden.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FeedsTableViewCell

    if (arrayofPostsFeed[indexPath.row].postedByUser!.nickName!) != arrayofPostsFeed[indexPath.row].ownedByUser!.nickName! {
        cell!.repostedFromLabel.text! = "Reposted From \(self.arrayofPostsFeed[indexPath.row].postedByUser!.nickName!)"
    } else {
        cell!.repostedFromLabel.hidden = true
    }
}
```

how should I prevent reusable cells to override each others?

Comment: reuse them properly by configuring them fully...

Comment: try cell!.repostedFromLabel.hidden = false if your condition is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the prepareForReuse function in your FeedsTableViewCell to reset the hidden property of the repostedFromLabel. Something like this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.repostedFromLabel.hidden = false
}
```

At the moment you are not resetting that value, so it will get mixed up when reusing the cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedsTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FeedsTableViewCell
    if (arrayofPostsFeed[indexPath.row].postedByUser!.nickName!) != arrayofPostsFeed[indexPath.row].ownedByUser!.nickName! {
        cell!.repostedFromLabel.text! = "Reposted From \(self.arrayofPostsFeed[indexPath.row].postedByUser!.nickName!)"
        cell!.repostedFromLabel.hidden = false
        }else {
        cell!.repostedFromLabel.hidden = true
        }
```